# How to change/customize getItem method in custom array adapter?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I want to make a custom getItem method in my custom adapter class. However, when I replace the default getItem with the custom one, I get an error that tells me tht I have to implement the default getItem method because I extend BaseAdapter.
When I have both of them in there, it is still just returning null when I use it in my activity.

```
public ImageView getItem(int rowNum, int columnNum)
{
    return gridContent[rowNum][columnNum];
}

public Object getItem(int i)
{
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have your  class extends ArrayAdapter

A specific type I belive in this case is ImageView :-?

try this :

```
 public T getItem(int rowNum, int columnNum)
      {
         return gridContent[rowNum][columnNum];
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not work,I have same problem.if you want to get item,you can save your item into HashMap,the index is position.Maybe you can use ArrayAdapter,but it can only execute simple function!
public T getItem(int rowNum, int columnNum)
      {
         return gridContent[rowNum][columnNum];
     }